# Brew MySQL mapped as MariaDB on Monterey? Issues!

Tags: homebrew, mysql, monterey

Hello I have installed Homebrew versions of Apache, PHP and MYSQL on Monterey, however I am experiencing some issues when restoring a database which was created on another "pure" MySQL server. The custom tool which is used to restore the database on my Mac, will throw warnings concerning inconsistencies on the (restore) database server:

> STATUS character set and collation isn't supported on current
> database. "Legacy Character set" and "Legacy Collation" will be
> replaced with default values. DETAILS This test checks to make sure
> this database can support the character set and collations found in
> the dup-installer/dup-database__[HASH].sql script.
>
> Character set list utf8    utf8mb4     Collations list latin1_general_ci
> utf8_general_ci    utf8_unicode_ci     utf8mb4_unicode_520_ci
> utf8mb4_unicode_ci     The database where the package was created has a
> character set and collation that is not supported on this server. This
> issue happens when a site is moved from an newer version of MySQL to a
> older version of MySQL. The recommended fix is to update MySQL on this
> server to support the character set that is failing below. If this is
> not an option for your host, then you can continue the installation.
> Invalid values will be replaced with the default values. For more
> details about this issue and other details regarding this issue see
> the FAQ link below.
>
> Default charset and setting in current installation DB_CHARSET =
> utf8mb4 DB_COLLATE = utf8mb4_general_ci

So I have verified MySQL version which was used to backup:
[image]

And and restore version:
[image]

I wonder if this issue is due to inconsistent character set and collating sequence (can this be fixed somehow?) or if the issues are due to MariaDB on the receiving end?

Comment: From the error message: "This issue happens when a site is moved from an newer version of MySQL to a older version of MySQL."

Comment: "The recommended fix is to update MySQL on this server to support the character set that is failing below. If this is not an option for your host, then you can continue the installation. Invalid values will be replaced with the default values. For more details about this issue and other details regarding this issue see the FAQ link below."

Comment: So what exactly is the question here?

Comment: Firstly I'm trying to understand why Homebrew MySQL is appearing as MariaDB type, secondly if this can cause issues. Lastly if is there a way to fix wrong/missing character set and collating sequence

Comment: Not so easy to figure this out from the question. Which Homebrew packages did you install? And "The recommended fix is to update MySQL on this server to support the character set that is failing below" so as said: the answer seems to be already in the error message.

Comment: this is the command I have used: brew install mysql

Comment: This should install mysql. Actually you can't install both mysql and mariadb via Homebrew because both use the same name for the binaries.

Comment: OTOH you very obviously are running an Homebrew installed MariaDB. Did you check in `$(brew --prefix)/Cellar` what actually is installed (run `ls -ld $(brew --prefix)/Cellar/m*` to check).

Comment: drwxr-xr-x  3 rick  admin  96 Dec 15 14:43 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/m4
drwxr-xr-x  3 rick  admin  96 Dec 15 21:04 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mecab
drwxr-xr-x  3 rick  admin  96 Dec 15 21:04 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mecab-ipadic
drwxr-xr-x  3 rick  admin  96 Dec 15 21:04 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/msgpack
drwxr-xr-x  3 rick  admin  96 Dec 17 11:56 /opt/homebrew/Cellar/mysql

Comment: From which applications are the screenshots in your question?

Comment: phpmyadmin screenshots, one from the production site and one from my mac

Comment: Removed MariaDB and downgraded to 5.7!